# How to fix this error, i use Nodejs and ExpressJs TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new' in

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Error TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'

I can't request an API and there is a response like that, How to fix this error?

My PatientPhysiqueModel.Js

```
import Patient from "./PatientModel.js";
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import database from "../Config/Database.js";

const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;

const PatientPhysique = database.define(
  "PatientPhysique",
  {
    bmi: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    weight: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
    }, ....{}
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
  }
);

PatientPhysique.belongsTo(Patient, {
  foreignKey: "PatientId",
  as: "patient",
});

export default PatientPhysique;
```

This my controller js

```
export const GetPatientPhysiqueById = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const patientPhysique = await PatientPhysique.findOne({
      where: {
        PatientId: id,
      },
    });
    res.json(patientPhysique);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Database.js

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

const database = new Sequelize("mcu", "root", "", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
});

export default database;
```

Comment: Paste the contents of `Database.js` into your question please.

Comment: Please add `PatientModel` model module as well

Comment: @Anatoly,

this my PatientModel.js



`
import database from "../Config/Database.js";
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;

const Patient = database.define(
  "Patient",
  {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    gender: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ,...{}
  ,
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
  }
);

export default Patient;
`

Comment: Have you run `sequelize.authenticate()` anywhere? Or in your case it would be `database.authenticate()`.

Comment: Also please add the full error description to the post